# Pokemon Go Soft Ban?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing Pokemon go for a while and decided to GPS spoof down the road to a pokestop as it was late at night. Anyway I spun the pokestop and it will give me the items however I have the soft ban effect of all Pokemon fleeing.Is this a ban or no???

Comment: I don't think anyone will give you a respectful answer for one reason : Cheating is heavily frowned upon in the Arqade community..

Comment: If you know you've been banned for cheating then why ask if you've been banned? You answered your question in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a softban. Wait a bit without playing to get it lifted.

We don't know if this can or will be extended to a permanent ban in the future, possibly with banwaves, but if you don't want to risk a ban or a softban, you should avoid gps spoofing as it is not allowed by the ToS.

Comment: There is zero proof this is a soft ban.

Comment: I wonder if you set your time forwards in the settings you can bypass the softban..

Comment: @Frank I had been softbanned before, and I had the same effect of all pokemon fleeing. I've also seen that sometimes pokestops work while pokemons are not catchable while softbanned.

Comment: @Riftcaster unlikely.

Comment: @Riftcaster With how much it's a server based game I highly doubt something as simple as changing the time would do anything at all.

Comment: I tried it with pokemon stops, the stop turned blue from purple but it didn't work, guessed it had to do with how unlocalised the game is most of the time.